# how i can handle multiple exceptions from number of different methods using only one try-catch block in java?

Tags: java

In this code there are two exceptions but i m unable to print both of them.Only one Exception is showing in the output.I want to show all the exceptions while executing the program once.

```
public class OneTry {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 5;
    int c;

    public void divide() {
        c = y / x;
        System.out.println("Divide" + c);
    }
    public void arr() {
        int a[] = new int[2];
        System.out.println(a[3]);
    }
    public void sum() {
        c = x + y;
        System.out.println("Sum" + c);
    }
    public void mult() {
        c = x * y;
        System.out.println("mult" + c);
    }
    public static void main(String abc[]) {

        OneTry obj = new OneTry();

        try {
            obj.divide();

            obj.arr();

            obj.mult();

            obj.sum();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | ArithmeticException e2) {
            System.out.println(e2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are 2 exceptions? You're simply catching 2 different exceptions, but that doesn't mean both are being thrown.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is the sort of exception that you should _never_ catch.

Comment: If your application throws a exception and is entering the catch block, the excecution of the try block is canceled.

Comment: An exception terminates execution.

Comment: Exceptions don't work the way you think they do. Once the program throws one exception, execution will move to the catch block and there is no opportunity for it to throw the second exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your program throws only ArithmeticException exception, because of the method call `obj.divide();`.

The flow of you program is interrupted by this exception and it falls in the catch block. The methods after `obj.divide();` are not called that means the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will never been thrown with your inputs.

If you want to test the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  comment the first method call.

In general, I can't think of a scenario that you can throw more than one exception within the same try block